# Are these logical operations the same?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

```
(day == ("Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday"))

OR

(day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday"|| day == "Wednesday")
```

I am putting them in an "IF" condition and I am not sure if they do the same thing ?

Comment: To make sure they aren't the same, try to console.log with Tuesday.

Comment: The expression with parenthesis will be evaluated first and the day will be compared with the result of the expression i.e. Monday. It will return false for any of the two other options.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Expressions wrapped by parentheses are evaluated first. In your snippet, that means in this line:

```
(day == ("Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday"))
```

The `("Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday")` is evaluated first before considering anything else. Those are three non-empty strings - and non-empty strings are *truthy*. Because JavaScript uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), the expression will evaluate to the first truthy value, `"Monday"`, every single time.

Thus, the first condition is equivalent to this:

```
(day == "Monday")
```

And the second condition to this, as it's written:

```
(day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday"|| day == "Wednesday")
```

---

If you'd like to check one variable against many values at once, I strongly suggest using arrays. The following condition is logically equivalent to your second condition:

```
(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"].includes(day))
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way to check the variable "day" without typing it so many times?

Comment: @Alexander I would suggest using an array. This is short and to the point: `(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"].includes(day))`

Comment: possible to use string also `"MondayTuesdayWednesday".includes(day)`, but array is probably better

Comment: That does work, but I would recommend against it due to being less efficient and less readable. Using an array you get early-exit on comparing the first character for non-matches, with a string it will iterate over each substring making many more comparisons.

Comment: @Klaycon Thanks, I will remember this method!

Comment: Note you could also create an object where the values are the object keys and just check for existence, eg `days={'monday':1,'tuesday':1,...}; if( day in days )...`